# Slow Vimeo upload speed using library compared to direct upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using [this](https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload/tree/master) library to upload videos from my web app to Vimeo. It is working fine. However, I need some assistance please in relation to the uploading speed. I have run two tests to determine why my implementation of the library is rather quite slow compared to uploading the same video directly onto the Vimeo Platform.

I observed a major thing which had me quite concerned and I just had to reach out for assistance. I observed that, when I opened my Task Manager in windows to observe the network performance, I can see that my upload using the library indicates that my upload speed is averaging/locking around 2Mbps while the upload directly is averaging around 20Mbps hence the upload directly on the Vimeo site is around 10 times faster.

I tried researching about this issue and the closest I got to an explanation is what one writer termed the size of the upload chunk. According to the writer, in their case, this problem was because the upload chunk was around 100Kb and the solution was just to change this size to make it bigger, say to 1Mb and the upload became faster. However, this was a whole different situation uploading to some other place, not Vimeo. Trying to look for the same situation in the library, I have realized that there doesn't seem to be any defined upload chunk size or its somewhere and I can't locate it.

My request is for you to kindly please assist me with tips and hints to make uploads from the library as fast as directly uploading to Vimeo.

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That websemantics library, at current time, [does not provide a version header in its requests](https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload/issues/31#issuecomment-389265937). Because no version header is provided, the Vimeo API defaults to the version specified on your [app management page](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps). If you have an older application defaulting to <3.4, then that library will work for uploading. If you have a newer application defaulting to >3.4, that library will not work for uploading unless the library is modified to include a version header.

All that being said, the "upload chunk" size you mention only applies to uploads using open source tus. The websemantics library does not use tus, instead it uses an older resumable upload method that has been [deprecated by Vimeo](https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/vimeo-is-adopting-tus-d5e999acd517).

Vimeo provides a [NodeJS library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js#uploading-videos) that is in active development and supported by Vimeo. Internally, the library uses the tus upload method, as implemented by Vimeo. The library will send the video file all at once, not in chunks, from the client.

I suggest migrating to the Vimeo Node library first, or another library that supports Vimeo's tus implementation, and once that is up and running, evaluate any upload speed issues you may encounter.

Comment: Makes sense, let me work on the node.js library. Thank you

Comment: Hi, i have been looking into this library and i managed to make it work from my desktop. its awesomely fast. Just the kind of speed i am expecting. Challenge now is, How do i integrate this into my asp.net project. I am very new to Node.js (started working on it this vimeo library). I am looking at your official libraries and you dont have an official asp.net library. Whats the best library to use?

Comment: Hi, I have had time playing around with the php official library as well and i observed that the node.js library is the best library i would wish to use. Whats the best implementation design to integrate with an ASP.Net project?

Comment: There are some unofficial ASP libraries listed on the libraries page (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries), that said the Vimeo API is built on HTTP requests, so if you know how to make an HTTP request in the language of your choice, you can use the Vimeo API.

Comment: I have modified and now i am trying to upload using the API and the TUS plugin. I am now getting the missing location header error, i have explained in detail here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647773/missing-location-header]. It seems vimeo does not return a location header in its response, How do i get this header on vimeo response?